# Dismount a VHDx file mounted in a folder?

Tags: powershell, vhd

On a usb drive, I have a VHDx file (which is bitlocked).

I want to create two scripts to quickly mount and dismount the VHDx file on Windows 8 system.

I want to mount the drive in a subfolder on my usb disk.

I succeed in writing the mount script:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

$vhdPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\_private\crypted.vhdx"
$mountPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\Data"

if(-not (Get-ChildItem $mountPath -Force)) # check if not already mounted
{
    Mount-VHD -NoDriveLetter -Path $mountPath
}
else{
    Write-Warning "Already mounted"
}
```

However, the dismount script does not works:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

$vhdPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\_private\crypted.vhdx"
$mountPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\Data"

if(Get-ChildItem $mountPath) # check if not already mounted
{
    Dismount-VHD -Path $vhdPath
}
else{
    Write-Warning "Not mounted"
}
```

The `Dismount-VHD -Path $vhdPath` throw an error :

> Dismount-VHD : Élément N:_private\crypted.vhdx introuvable.

(can be translated to something like `item N:\_private\crypted.vhdx introuvable cannot be found`)

I also try with `Dismount-VHD -Path $mountPath`, but I get another exception:

> Dismount-VHD : Le paramètre n’est pas valide. « N:\Data » n’est pas un fichier de disque dur virtuel existant.

(translation: Invalid parameter: n:\Data  is not a disk file)

What is the correct way to dismount a VHD file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a [technet thread,](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/59ffd7c0-95a8-4ffe-bfc7-0ebf0f2f74b0/how-to-dismount-a-vhdx-file-mounted-in-a-folder#59cd8fab-2b9f-43ea-86b7-d76170b24ea4) I finally made my scripts work:

The final working scripts are these ones:

### Mount.ps1 :

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

$vhdPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\_private\crypted.vhdx"
$mountPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\Data"

if(-not (Get-ChildItem $mountPath -ea SilentlyContinue)) # check if not already mounted
{
    $diskPartScriptContent = @( 
        "select vdisk file=$vhdPath", 
        "attach vdisk"
        )
    $diskPartScriptFile = Join-Path $scriptDir "_diskpart.tmp"
    Set-Content  -Path $diskPartScriptFile -Value $diskPartScriptContent
    $result = (& diskpart.exe /s $diskPartScriptFile)

    & mountvol n:\data "\\?\Volume{820c8453-f504-11e2-bedd-9e2cd2a4b688}"

}
else{
    Write-Warning "Already mounted"
}
```

### Dismount.ps1:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

$vhdPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\_private\crypted.vhdx"
$mountPath = Join-Path $scriptDir "\Data"

if(Get-ChildItem $mountPath -ea SilentlyContinue) # check if not already mounted
{
    $diskPartScriptContent = @( 
        "select vdisk file=$vhdPath", 
        "detach vdisk"
        )
    $diskPartScriptFile = Join-Path $scriptDir "_diskpart.tmp"
    Set-Content  -Path $diskPartScriptFile -Value $diskPartScriptContent
    & diskpart.exe /s $diskPartScriptFile
    & mountvol $mountPath /d

}
else{
    Write-Warning "Not mounted"
}
```

I hardcoded the volume ID in my mount script. If someone knows a way to get this automatically, I'd appreciate.

But I can live with that by now, because my volume is always the same.